# My bootstrap classes were working just fine but suddenly stopped working

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

My bootsrap was working just fine but suddenly just stopped working. I have tried the online link and downloaded source file but still not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link href="HALOGENCSS.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-flex">
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <img src="log.JPG" alt="logo" id="logo" style="width: 120px; height: 120px;"/>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <img src="dropdown.png" alt="dropdown button" id="dropdown" style="width: 30px; height: 30px;"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check in the network tab, are they loading? do you see any error?

Comment: @Sameer I am using the compiled source code

Comment: @Sameer I just used this link from freecodecamp and it worked fine. Lol

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"/>